# Add kinesis stream into DynamoDB Global table

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-cloudformation, amazon-kinesis

I can able to add manually kinesis stream to DynamoDB Global Table for each region .I am keeping the stream as region specific .While adding using Cloudformation template getting error **"Resource handler returned message: "Invalid request provided: To enable Kinesis Data Stream in DynamoDBTable, both the stream and table must be in the same region."**

The CFT I am using for creation is ,

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
Description: 'AWS CloudFormation Template for DynamoDB tables For Flight Information Service'
Parameters:
  flightInformation:
    Type: String
    Description: Select dynamodb table name 
    Default: FlightInformationtest
  BillingMode:
    Description: Provisioned scaling mode
    Type: String
    Default: 'PAY_PER_REQUEST'
    AllowedValues:
      - 'PROVISIONED'
      - 'PAY_PER_REQUEST'
  FlightInfoStream:
    Description: "Flight info service kinesis stream arn"
    Type: "AWS::SSM::Parameter::Value<String>"
    Default: /flightinfo/kinesis/arn       
  AWSCurrentRegion: 
    Type: String
    Default: us-east-1  
  AWSReplicatedRegion: 
    Type: String
    Default: us-west-2 
  CFNStreamName:
    Description: This will be used to name the Kinesis DataStream
    Type: String
    Default: 'BDT-Flightinfo-Stream'
  CFNRetensionHours:
    Description: This will be used to set the retension hours
    Type: Number
    Default: 48    
Resources:
  FlightInformation: 
    Type: AWS::DynamoDB::GlobalTable
    Properties:
      TableName: !Ref flightInformation
      BillingMode: !Ref BillingMode
      AttributeDefinitions:
        - 
          AttributeName: "partitionKey"
          AttributeType: "S"
        - 
          AttributeName: "sortKey"
          AttributeType: "S"
      KeySchema: 
        - 
          AttributeName: "partitionKey"
          KeyType: "HASH"
        - 
          AttributeName: "sortKey"
          KeyType: "RANGE"          
      StreamSpecification:
        StreamViewType: NEW_AND_OLD_IMAGES
      SSESpecification:
        SSEEnabled: true
        SSEType: "KMS"    
      Replicas:
      - Region: !Ref AWSCurrentRegion
        KinesisStreamSpecification:
          StreamArn: !Ref FlightInfoStream    
        PointInTimeRecoverySpecification: 
          PointInTimeRecoveryEnabled: true        
      - Region: !Ref AWSReplicatedRegion
        KinesisStreamSpecification:
          StreamArn: !Ref FlightInfoStream      
        PointInTimeRecoverySpecification: 
          PointInTimeRecoveryEnabled: true
```

if we can attached the kinesis stream that is region specific to global DynamoDB for both the region that would be great !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You tried to pass the same stream ARN into both regions, which will not work. Ensure that you pass the correct stream ARN into each replica, for that given region:

```
      Replicas:
      - Region: !Ref AWSCurrentRegion
        KinesisStreamSpecification:
          StreamArn: <stream arn from  us-east-1 >    
        PointInTimeRecoverySpecification: 
          PointInTimeRecoveryEnabled: true        
      - Region: !Ref AWSReplicatedRegion
        KinesisStreamSpecification:
          StreamArn: <stream arn from  us-west-2 >     
        PointInTimeRecoverySpecification: 
          PointInTimeRecoveryEnabled: true
```

Comment: no I am passing respective  stream arn which is region specific and stored in ssm parameter .

Comment: Sorry my bad ,by mistake I was using the same stream arn .Thanks a lot .